# Reformatting procrustes coordinates in R

Tags: r, geometry, format, morphological-analysis

I've performed a procrustes analysis on 164 files of wing shape data each with 8 landmarks using;

```
 Procrustescoords <- list()
 for (a in 1:length(flightfiles)){
 Procrustescoords <-c(Procrustescoords,gpagen(array(data=Flights[,,a],dim=c(8,2,1)), Proj= TRUE, ShowPlot  = TRUE, ProcD = TRUE, PrinAxes = TRUE, curves = NULL, surfaces = NULL)[1])
```

Which produces outputs for each individual of;

```
$coords
, , 1

        [,1]        [,2]
[1,] -0.46629916  0.01094528
[2,] -0.17442692  0.07026679
[3,]  0.17749109  0.10209531
[4,]  0.35896138  0.02312385
[5,]  0.36198915  0.01257036
[6,]  0.28832972 -0.05956911
[7,]  0.03323332 -0.14496370
[8,] -0.57927857 -0.01446878
```

The output of str(Procrustescoords) is;

```
> str(Procrustescoords)

List of 164

 $ coords: num [1:8, 1:2, 1] 0.493 0.315 -0.269 -0.269 -0.269 ...
 $ coords: num [1:8, 1:2, 1] 0.472 0.197 -0.1 -0.364 -0.371 ...
 $ coords: num [1:8, 1:2, 1] -0.485 -0.134 0.115 0.355 0.359 ...
 $ coords: num [1:8, 1:2, 1] 0.39136 0.30866 0.05409 -0.0059 -0.00196 ...
 $ coords: num [1:8, 1:2, 1] 0.479 0.309 -0.188 -0.327 -0.33 ...
 $ coords: num [1:8, 1:2, 1] 0.107 0.149 0.267 0.29 0.288 ...
 $ coords: num [1:8, 1:2, 1] 0.496 0.202 -0.236 -0.309 -0.327 ...
 $ coords: num [1:8, 1:2, 1] 0.488 0.2 -0.249 -0.317 -0.33 ...
```

...and so on for all 164 individuals

I am now looking to reformat the output coordinates into a table where each row is an individual (file) and the coordinates are presented as columns such as "X1", "Y1", "X2", "Y2",... "X8", "Y8".
So far I am really struggling how to do this.

Any help would be great. 
Thanks

Comment: it's not clear how the $coords are nested inside the Procrustescoords object, can you paste in the output of str(Procrustescoords)

Comment: I've added the output of the str(Procrustescoords)

Thanks

Comment: How about `matrix(unlist(Procrustescoords), ncol = (2*length(Procrustescoords)))` then assign column names with `paste0(c("X", "Y"), rep(seq_along(Procrustescoords), each=2))`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using

```
ProcTable <- matrix(nrow=length(Specimens),ncol=16)
    rownames(ProcTable)<-Specimens
    for (x in 1:length(Specimens)){
     flight<-read.table(flightfiles[x],skip=1,col.names=c("x","y"), nrow = length(readLines(flightfiles[x])) - 2)
  ProcTable[x,1]<-flight[1,1]
  ProcTable[x,3]<-flight[2,1]
  ProcTable[x,5]<-flight[3,1]
  ProcTable[x,7]<-flight[4,1]
  ProcTable[x,9]<-flight[5,1]
  ProcTable[x,11]<-flight[6,1]
  ProcTable[x,13]<-flight[7,1]
  ProcTable[x,15]<-flight[8,1]
  ProcTable[x,2]<-flight[1,2]
  ProcTable[x,4]<-flight[2,2]
  ProcTable[x,6]<-flight[3,2]
  ProcTable[x,8]<-flight[4,2]
  ProcTable[x,10]<-flight[5,2]
  ProcTable[x,12]<-flight[6,2]
  ProcTable[x,14]<-flight[7,2]
  ProcTable[x,16]<-flight[8,2]
}
```